# ssh always prompts for key password

Tags: command-line, ssh, seahorse

I'm using 12.10 with gnome-shell 3.6.

I have multiple ssh keypairs (created with ssh-keygen). They're stored in ~/.ssh/ids/hostname/id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. I have a file ~/.ssh/config which says which key to use with which host.

Whenever I connect to one of the hosts, it always prompts me for the id_rsa password. I want the keys to be unlocked whenever I'm logged in.

I tried to import the keys into seahorse (aka Passwords and Keys), but I ran against this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/1017210

I then tried to use ssh-add. This gave me the proper behavior, but it didn't persist across sessions/reboots.

Before I created different keys for different hosts, gnome-shell would give me a popup asking for my login password, and after I entered it, the keys would be unlocked for the rest of the session. How can I get this to work again?

Comment: check out this link, make sure you correctly transfered the public key to the server https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Transfer_Client_Key_to_Host

Comment: I did correctly transfer them. As I mentioned, when I used ssh-add to unlock the private keys, I could log in to the various hosts with no problem (and no password, either from my account on that host and from the keyfile).

Answer (score 1):

Seahorse will automatically detect the ssh keyfiles if they're in the top-level `~/.ssh` directory. My work-around solution was to change how I organized my keyfiles. As such, seahorse detects them, and gnome-shell detects them only asks for my login password once per keyfile.